# FindName failing on TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I have created a custom control with a XAML template applied to it.  Within the custom control, I need to manipulate an image.  To do that, I am attempting to use FindName to find the image in OnApplyTemplate.  However, FindName is returning null.  The code:

```
public class QaTabItem : TabItem
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HotKeyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("HotKey", typeof(string), typeof(QaTabItem));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TabImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TabImage", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(QaTabItem));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), typeof(QaTabItem));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CaptionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Caption", typeof(string), typeof(QaTabItem));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OrientationProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Orientation", typeof(TabOrientation), typeof(QaTabItem));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IndexProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Index", typeof(double), typeof(QaTabItem));
    private Image arrowImage;

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        arrowImage = base.Template.FindName("ArrowImage", this) as Image;
    }
}
```

The template:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}" x:Key="ImageRotater">
    <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5, 0.5" />
    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:QaTabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:QaTabItem}">                 
                <Border x:Name="ContentBorder"
                Margin="0"
                Background="{DynamicResource AiButtonGreyBrush}"
                BorderBrush="{DynamicResource AiWhiteBrush}"
                BorderThickness="0,.1,0,0">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="33*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="33*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="33*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label 
                            Grid.Row="0" 
                            Grid.Column="3" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                            Foreground="{DynamicResource AiGreyBrush}" 
                            FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding HotKey}" />
                        <StackPanel 
                            Grid.Row="1" 
                            Grid.Column="0" 
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                            Orientation="Horizontal" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <Image  
                                Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                                Grid.Column="0" 
                                Stretch="Uniform" 
                                Width="25" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                Source="{TemplateBinding TabImage}" />
                            <TextBlock 
                                TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                Margin="20,0,0,0" 
                                Width="75" 
                                Foreground="{DynamicResource AiWhiteBrush}" 
                                FontSize="14"
                                Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Label 
                            Grid.Row="2" 
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Caption}" 
                            Grid.Column="0" 
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                            FontSize="10" 
                            FontFamily="Segoe UI" 
                            FontWeight="Bold" 
                            Foreground="{DynamicResource AiGreyBrush}" />
                        <Image 
                            x:Name="ArrowImage" 
                            Grid.Row="1" 
                            Grid.Column="2" 
                            Source="{DynamicResource TabItemHeaderArrowIcon}" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                            Width="20" 
                            Height="20" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Any ideas why arrowImage in OnApplyTemplate is null when I try to create an instance of this control?

**Edit:** I failed to mention earlier that I am using this control as a base class for other controls.  When I go to use it, I add a WPF UserControl to my project and change its base class from UserControl to QaTabItem.  I haven't actually tried running the code as the failure is happening in the designer.

**Edit 2:**  Whoops.  Forgot my dependency properties in my class.

Comment: I've just tried your code and for me, FindName returns an image as expected. I changed the name of ArrowImage in the template and then I get null, so that is all working for me. This makes me think that your xaml template isn't getting applied correctly. Where is your style defined?

Comment: The style is defined in a separate xaml file.  When I subclass the control, I pull the xaml in using a resource dictionary.

Comment: Ok, that's how I have it set up too, strange. The only difference I can think of is that I had to remove these to make this compile: Content="{TemplateBinding HotKey}", Source="{TemplateBinding TabImage}", Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" Content="{TemplateBinding Caption}". Worth you trying to remove those just to see if it makes a difference to the test?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was half asleep when I posted this code.  I forgot to put my dependency properties in my code.  That's why you had to remove those before it would compile.

Comment: No worries, I just wondered if those bindings may have caused a difference in behaviour

Comment: I can't break your code, it is working as expected, not sure what else to try. If you wanted to include any additional source etc I'll take another look, but otherwise I'm stuck!

Comment: Thanks for looking at it.  After going over it with my other dev, we're going to take a different approach anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drew,

Unfortunately there is no way to utilize FindName within a template or style programmatically if the setter you are using is sealed.

From MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-uS/office/office365/windows.ui.xaml.setter.property.aspx

If you're accessing a Setter instance using code, you cannot change the value of any property of a Setter instance if the value of the `IsSealed` property on a parent Style is `true`. This is also reported by the `IsSealed` property on an individual Setter. The system sets these properties to true when the runtime applies styles to UI elements and displays them in the UI. Attempting to change a sealed Setter throws a runtime error.

However, all is not lost. I noticed that in your template, the control `ArrowImage` has a source that is a `DynamicResource`. Have you considered the possibility of setting the resource as an App Resource in code and manipulating that?

To set as an App Resource in code, add the following line to the `App.xaml.cs` file constructor

```
App.Current.Resources.Add("TabItemHeaderArrowIcon",null); // <-- Could replace null with a proper image source
```

Then in your code, you can reference the App Resource as follows,

```
App.Current.Resources["TabItemHeaderArrowIcon"] = your image source
```

On Application Close, make sure to clean up the App Resource (as it is allocated in memory) using

```
App.Current.Resources.Remove("TabItemHeaderArrowIcon")
```

This is a method that has worked for me in the past. Hopefully it will help you too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I actually went about it using style triggers, which is actually working out better for me anyway.

Comment: Thanks for marking this as the answer even though you already found another method.